# Deploy Azure mobile service code to Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

Currently, I have an **existed App Service (A)** that have 
 been migrated from Mobile Service. And now I want the newly created **App service (C)** work compatible with old code of (A).

I have deployed all files in **wwwroot** of (A) to (B) but unfortunately (B) can't access to Database
`request.service.tables.getTable('User').read....` will return `Error: Internal Server Error`
Does anyone know this issue? 
Is able to deploy old code of Mobile Service (or the App Service migrated from Mobile service) to the new App Service?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for moving from Mobile Services to App Service: migration or upgrade. Either option will give you access to all of the hosting capabilities of App Service:

- Migrating a service just changes the underlying environment that
  hosts your mobile backend. It requires no code changes to either the
  mobile client or the mobile server project. If you use the automated
  migration option, this preserves your service.azure-mobile.net URL.
- Upgrading a service does require code changes to both your server and
  client project but allows you to take advantage of new mobile SDK
  features, such as improvements to authentication and more flexibility
  for your server project.

For more details, refer to [Migrate your existing Azure Mobile Service to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services).

Since you have not provided complete error message details, I suggest you [Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) in case if you haven’t enabled earlier to check the complete error details.

Hope this helps.